# Type mismatch with Async in F#

Tags: f#

I've just started messing around with F# and am trying to do some basic parallel computation to get familiar with the language. I'm having trouble with type mismatches. Here's an example:

```
let allVariances list =
    seq {
        for combination in allCombinations list do
            yield (combination, abs(targetSum - List.sum combination))
    }

let compareVariance tup1 tup2 =
    if snd tup1 < snd tup2 then
        tup1
    else
        tup2

let aCompareVariance tup1 tup2 =
    async { return compareVariance tup1 tup2 }

let matchSum elements targetSum =
    allVariances elements
    |> Seq.reduce aCompareVariance
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

So, "allVariances elements" produces a seq`<float list * float`>. CompareVariance takes two of those `<float list * float`> tuples and returns the one with the smaller second item (variance). My goal is to use Reduce to end up with the tuple with the smallest variance. However, I get a type mismatch on the aCompareVariance argument:

Error   1   Type mismatch. Expecting a     float list * float -> float list * float -> float list * float     but given a     float list * float -> float list * float -> Async`<float list * float`>     The type 'float list * float' does not match the type 'Async`<float list * float`>'

It seems like the Async return type isn't accepted by Reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq.reduce` takes a function and a sequence and reduces the list using the function.  That is, the outcome of reducing a sequence `{a1;a2;a3;...;an}` with function `f` will be `f(f(...f(f(a1,a2),a3),...),an))...)`.  However, the function you're passing can't be applied this way, because the return type (`Async<float list * float>`) doesn't match the argument types (`float list * float`).  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Also, keep in mind that `async` computations are great for asynchronous work, but not ideal for parallel work.  See [F#: Asynch and Tasks and PLINQ, oh my!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178608/f-asynch-and-tasks-and-plinq-oh-my) and [Task Parallel Library vs Async Workflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871168/f-task-parallel-library-vs-async-workflows).

**EDIT**

Here's one way to write a function which will reduce items more like you expected, operating sort of like this:

```
[|a1; a2; a3; a4|]
[|f a1 a2; f a3 a4|]
f (f a1 a2) (f a3 a4)
```

At each stage, all applications of f will take place in parallel.  This uses `Async.Parallel`, which as mentioned above is probably less appropriate than using the Task Parallel Library (and may even be slower than just doing a normal synchronous `Array.reduce`).  As such, just consider this to be demonstration code showing how to piece together the async functions.

```
let rec reduce f (arr:_[]) =
  match arr.Length with
  | 0 -> failwith "Can't reduce an empty array"
  | 1 -> arr.[0]
  | n ->
      // Create an array with n/2 tasks, each of which combines neighboring entries using f
      Array.init ((n+1)/2) 
        (fun i -> 
           async { 
             // if n is odd, leave last item alone
             if n = 2*i + 1 then
               return arr.[2*i]
             else
               return f arr.[2*i] arr.[2*i+1]}) 
      |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
      |> reduce f
```

Note that converting items to and from `Async` values all happens internally to this function, so it has the same type as `Array.reduce` and would be used with your normal `compareVariance` function rather than with `aCompareVariance`.

Comment: I guess I had the wrong idea about reduce. I was hoping that it would work more like this for a sequence {a1;a2;a3;a4}: f( f(a1,a2), f(a3,a4) ). If it was executed like that, f(a1,a2) and f(a3,a4) could run in parallel.

Comment: @user282232 - Even in that case, you'd want the input and output types for `f` to match, since the outermost `f` acts on the output from previous reduction steps.

Comment: So why don't those types match? A `<float list * float`> is what it is, whether it's coming from another thread or the same one.

Comment: @user282232 - Those types can't match.  An `Async<x>` is a computation that will return an `x`; this is different from a value of type `x` that has already been calculated.  You can convert from one to the other using `async.Return` and `Async.RunSynchronously`, but the types can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So when I see:

    [for i in 0..10 -> i]

    |> Seq.map (fun x -> async { return x*2 })

    |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously

What's happening is that the map returns a sequence of not-yet-performed computations, and then the Async stuff executes those in a parallel manner and returns their results in an array?

Comment: @user282232 - That's correct.  I've updated my answer to show how to define a parallel reduction operator that probably works more like you were hoping.  Pay attention to the caveats, though!